# Probability Distribution for the Difference of Random Variables?

Tags: probability

I was reading this link on Probability Distributions of Random Variables (https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_2_sums_random_variables.php) and had the following question on the **distribution of functions of random variables.**

To give some context to this question, consider the following example:

Let $X$ be some random variable with some arbitrary (i.e. does not need to be Normally Distributed). probability density function $f(x)$, and let $Y$ be some random variable with probability density function $f(y)$. Let $Z = X - Y$. **Suppose are interested in the probability density function $f(z)$ of $Z$.**

To answer this question, (I think) we can use "Convolutions of Probability Distributions" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). Therefore, the probability density function $f(z)$ of $Z = X - Y$ is:

$$ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) dx $$
$$ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(z-y) f_Y(y) dy $$

And now, using a "proof by counterexample", I think it is now possible to show that we can find some $f(x)$ and some $f(y)$ such that $Z$ does not follow a Normal Distribution.

For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Exponential Random Variables with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. The probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$ are given by:

$$f_X(x) = \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}, \quad x \geq 0$$
$$f_Y(y) = \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y}, \quad y \geq 0$$

Let $Z = X - Y$.  The probability density function of $Z$ can be found by convolution:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) dx$$

Substituting the expressions for $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, we get:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} \lambda_2 e^{\lambda_2 (x - z)} dx$$

Simplifying, we get:

$$f_Z(z) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 z} \int_{0}^{z} e^{-(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) x} dx$$

Solving the integral, we get:

$$f_Z(z) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 z} \frac{1 - e^{-(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) z}}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}$$

And here we can clearly see that $f_Z(z)$ is not Normally Distributed.

This being said,  **we have shown that the difference in any two Random Variables is not necessarily Normal - but is the difference between the means of these two Random Variables necessarily Normally Distributed?**

Using Central Limit Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), I think we can argue that the Expected Value of any Random Variable follows a Normal Distribution. And we also know that the sums and differences of Normally Distributed Random Variables are also Normally Distributed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). Therefore, I think the argument can be made that the difference in means of any two Random Variables (regardless of their distributions) is Asymptotically Normally Distributed.

From a practical perspective, suppose we are interested in testing whether the means from two different populations are statistically different - we have just shown that the difference in means from any two Random Variables are always Asymptotically Normally Distributed, regardless of the Probability Distribution for these Random Variables.

**My Question:** If this is all true, then we do we have Non-Parametric Tests (i.e. distribution free) such as the Mann-Whitney Test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) for testing the difference between the means of two random variables - when we know that difference  in means from any two Random Variables are always Asymptotically Normally Distributed?

Thanks!

Comment: For familiar term for the joint pdf is $$f_Z(z)=\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2\cdot \frac{e^{\lambda_1\cdot z}-e^{\lambda_2\cdot z}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$$

Comment: The reason why $X-Y$ are not (asymptotically) normal distributed is that you have **two variables** only. Thus the clt cannot be applied. Comprehensible?

Comment: @ callculus: thank you so much for your reply! Do you have any comments about the non-parametric tests I mentioned towards the end?

Comment: *Sample* means are random variables, while *means* are synonymous with *expected values* and these are obviously not random.

Comment: Your formula for $f_Z$ is the density of the sum $X+Y$, not of the difference $X-Y$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a lot to say in response to the question, so I'll go line by line. The computations are fine, except you computed $X + Y$. Afterwards, you write

> Using Central Limit Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem),

The CLT tells you the limiting distribution of a sampling average; in particular you need an arbitrarily large amount of samples (of course, if you are a statistician, $\infty \approx 40$ or so) to apply it. Certainly it is note relevant at all to $X - Y$ for $X, Y$ random variables.

> I think we can argue that the Expected Value of any Random Variable follows a Normal Distribution.

The expected value is just a number, e.g. $E[X] = 0$ if $X$ is standard normal for example; so the difference of expectations is not really normally distributed, and not even a random variable, really.

> And we also know that the sums and differences of Normally Distributed Random Variables are also Normally Distributed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

This is true.

> Therefore, I think the argument can be made that the difference in means of any two Random Variables (regardless of their distributions) is Asymptotically Normally Distributed.

Asymptotically means nothing here: "asymptotically" needs an infinite sequence of random variables, and here you have 2. And again, the difference in means is just a number.

> From a practical perspective, suppose we are interested in testing whether the means from two different populations are statistically different - we have just shown that the difference in means from any two Random Variables are always Asymptotically Normally Distributed, regardless of the Probability Distribution for these Random Variables.

See above; there are issues with just about every part of "the difference in means from any two Random Variables are always Asymptotically Normally Distributed, regardless of the Probability Distribution for these Random Variables."

> My Question: If this is all true, then we do we have Non-Parametric Tests (i.e. distribution free) such as the Mann-Whitney Test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) for testing the difference between the means of two random variables - when we know that difference in means from any two Random Variables are always Asymptotically Normally Distributed?

Well, the above isn't true, but the way the Mann-Whitney test works is that it computes a statistic whose distribution is known under the null hypothesis that the two distributions are the same, and in that way goes around the issue of distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly pointed out by the first answer and in comments that the mean of a random variable is a fixed value and not a random variable hence the second half of the argument is pointless. However if we consider that as a typo and think about the underlying message:

> For two arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Y$, let $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$
> be the their sample mean, which, according to CLT, are normally
> distributed, is $Z:= \bar X - \bar Y$ also normally distributed? If so,
> what's the point of tests like Mann-Whitney Test?

First of all, there is a difference between *the sample mean of differences* $\overline{X - Y}$ and *the difference between sample means* $\bar X - \bar Y$, although both of them are (asymptotically) normally distributed. $\bar X - \bar Y$ is normally distributed because it's the difference of two normals; $\overline{X - Y}$ is normal because of CLT.

How Mann-Whitney works is that it draws independent samples $\{x_i\}$, $\{y_j\}$ from $X$ and $Y$, and calculate the U statistic based on values of $\{ x_i - y_j| \forall i, j\}$, so it has nothing to do with the sample means $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$, nor is it exactly the sample mean of differences $\overline{X-Y}$.

However if we change the setup of Mann-Whitney by a little bit - to draw from the two distributions **at the same time** and calculate the statistic based on the difference $\{ x_i - y_i| \forall i\}$, then it's basically testing if the expected value of the difference $X - Y$ is zero, i.e. $E[X-Y]=0$. Note that it's still different than testing the sample mean of difference $\overline{X-Y}$, which we know is normally distributed, even though $E[\overline{X -Y}]=E[X-Y]=E[X]-E[Y]$.

What matters in this test is the expected value, instead of the normality of the distribution. In another word, knowing that the difference is asymptotically normal does not increase or decrease the value of the test.